# How do you populate a list<Interface> from another method in another class? c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to write a program that allows you to create a weapon and it will store the results in a list (inventory). I'm having trouble populating that list once a weapon is created.

The list I have so far is

```
List<IEquipppable> Inventory = new List<IEquippable>();
```

That is in the Character class.

IEquippable being an Interface with only this in it

```
void Equip(Character character);
```

I have a method in the Program class that creates a weapon (MakeWeapon).

How do I store the weapon that is made into the list?

Thank you.

Comment: `Inventory.Add(someThing)`? Otherwise we are missing way too much context to make sense of your question. Where is your line that creates the inventory? Where is `MakeWeapon` what does that look like? How are they related? Who is supposed to own the list?

Comment: And Matt's something will have to implement IEquippable.

Comment: The `List<T>` class has an `.Add()` method for adding elements to it.  This should be pretty self-evident in the intellisense if you're using an IDE (which is recommended).

Comment: From a design standpoint, it might be more useful to have `.Equip(IEquippable equipment)` on the `Character`. rather than on the item..

Answer (score 3):

To insert a weapon, that weapon must implement the IEquippable interface.

```
public class Claymore: IEquippable
{
    public void Equip(Character character)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Freedom!");
    }
}
```

Then, create an instance of your weapon and add it to the list.

```
IEquppable mySword = new Claymore();
Inventory.Add(mySword);
```

Comment: I was actually thinking `Console.WriteLine("Front Toward Enemy");`  Different claymores for different folks I guess :)

Comment: Good point. What is great about using the interface is that you can write an entire library of different kinds of weapons. You can even make hierarchical abstract classes that cover swords, guns, sticks, slingshots, trebuchets, tactical nukes, and whatever other weapons you can think of. So, you could have a `public class MP40 : SubmachineGun<9mm> , IEquippable` that represents a German MP40 Submachine Gun that takes 9mm ammunition and can be equipped in someone's inventory.